# change graph dataframe by selecting button in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

tmp_df = {
"col_a" : [1,2,3,4,5,6], "col_b":[0,1,0,1,0,1], 
"col_c":[2,4,6,8,10,12], "col_d":[9,8,7,6,5,4]}
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(tmp_df)

fig = px.scatter_3d(data_frame = tmp_df, x="col_a",  y='col_c', z='col_d', color="col_b")
data_type = tmp_df.col_b.unique()
buttons = []
for counter, i in enumerate(data_type):
    buttons.append(dict(method='update',
                        label = '{}'.format(i),
                        args = [    {"data_frame" : tmp_df[tmp_df.col_b == i].to_json() # TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
                                }  ]
                        )
                   )
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(buttons=buttons, direction='down', x=0.1, y=1.15)])
fig.show()
```

hi. I'm pretty noob in plotly.

above code is 3d scatter graph about two types data with selecting buttons. (above code is simple example code. it runs without bug. )

I want to make it possible to select the data I want to see by pressing a button, but the button appears but does not work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.to_json()` which is invalid for the `data_frame` parameter of the `scatter_3d()` function, you can pass the dataframe directly.

Replace your `for` loop with the following.

```
for counter, i in enumerate(data_type):
    buttons.append(dict(method='update',
                        label='{}'.format(i),
                        args=[{"x": [tmp_df[tmp_df.col_b == i].col_a],
                               "y": [tmp_df[tmp_df.col_b == i].col_c],
                               "z": [tmp_df[tmp_df.col_b == i].col_d],
                               "type": "scatter3d",
                               "mode": "markers",
                               "marker": {"color": tmp_df[tmp_df.col_b == i].col_b.map({0: "red", 1: "blue"})}
                              }]
                       )
                  )
```